# Remove bottom border of header in React Native using useLayoutEffect hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, border

I want to remove the faint border from the bottom of the header in React Native. I'm using `useLayoutEffect()` hook to modify the header but unable to remove the border. I've tried using `borderBottomWidth: 0` inside `headerStyle` but it's not working.

```js
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
          title: "Signal",
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fff", borderBottomWidth: 0 },
          headerTitleStyle: { color: "#000" },
          headerTintColor: "#000",
        });
      }, [navigation]);
```

[Emulator screenshot showing the border line to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVIDi.png)

Answer (score 62):

Recently ran across this in React Navigation 6 but found there is another way. Per the docs there is [`headerShadowVisible`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headershadowvisible)

**Docs:**

Whether to hide the elevation shadow (Android) or the bottom border (iOS) on the header. This is a short-hand for the following styles:

```
{
  elevation: 0,
  shadowOpacity: 0,
  borderBottomWidth: 0,
}
```

If the above styles are specified in `headerStyle` along with `headerShadowVisible: false`, then `headerShadowVisible: false` will take precedence.

**Example:**

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Example"
  component={Example}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: route.params.title,
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: route.params.color,
    },
    headerShadowVisible: false, // applied here
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  })}
/>
```

Comment: is there a way to style the default header so that `headerShadowVisible: false` is automatically applies to any screen?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using react-navigation you remove the bottom border by specifying the following for the headerStyle in your navigationOptions:

```
headerStyle: {
  shadowColor: 'transparent', // this covers iOS
  elevation: 0, // this covers Android
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass the `headerShadowVisible: false` to navigation.setOptions({}).

In the example i am doing it with useLayout to avoid any UI issues with updates, i recommmend that you also do that if you need to set this in your screen.

Example:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: () => <Image source={source} />,
      headerShadowVisible: false,
    })
  }, [navigation])
```

Heres some documentation i found in the type file

```
   /**
     * Whether to hide the elevation shadow (Android) or the bottom border (iOS) on the header.
     */
    headerShadowVisible?: boolean;
    /**
     * Boolean indicating whether the navigation bar is translucent.
     * Setting this to `true` makes the header absolutely positioned,
     * and changes the background color to `transparent` unless specified in `headerStyle`.
     */
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
headerStyle: {
  borderWidth: 0,
  elevation: 0,
  shadowOpacity: 0,
},
```

Comment: Adding context to your answer helps convey your intent.